# How to trigger a particular build before a commit is made to other builds in vsts

Tags: azure-devops

I have a build say "test" under build and releases which is common build or dependent build to other builds like "test1" and "test2". I want the "test" build to run first before every commit is made to other builds "test1" and "test2" so that they can get the required dependencies form "test". Can you please let me know how this is achievable in vsts?

Regards,
Shwetha

Answer (score 0):

You can do it through Phase, simple steps:

1. If you are using **TFVC**, change Source to add common/dependent project mapping in Get sources.
2. If you are using **Git**: Select the Phase and check **All Script to access OAuth token** option. (Optional: Select **Options** tab and change **Project collection** in **Build job authorization scope** if the common/dependent project is in another team project)
3. Change Visual Studio build task to just build common/denpendent project in this phase
4. Add another agent phase to build other projects (e.g. test1, test 2)

Comment: All my projects are under a single branch and in same project. Can you please let me know how to implement the step 3 which you mentioned above? I have enabled the  All Script to access OAuth token option. But unable to find the relevant option for step 3 when I select Project collections. Request you to guide me on the same.

Comment: Do you mean the projects are in the same repository and branch? With this scenario, what's the "test" build used for? Why do you just build them together in a build?

Comment: :Nope all the other projects are on different repos and different branch with different functionalities done by the code. "test"has some common jars which need to be supplied to "test1"and "test2" before a commit takes place in these builds. Since "test1" and "test2"have different functionalities we cannot merge them together in build. Basically what I am looking for is "test"needs to run first and(to produce a jar ) before commit happens in "test2" or "test3" (jar produced is given to "test2" or "test3" just like any other third party jars which we supply for projects).

Comment: It isn't a .net project, so add related task to build common/dependent project  (Replace step 3)

Comment: Create 2 maven feeds (with mirrors). 1 for 'support' and 1 for 'release'. Until a release candidate for 'test' is approved new versions are only published to 'support' feed. Once 'test' is approved for release it will enter the pipeline and be published to the 'release' feed. Then restrict consuming application build definitions to only have visibility to 1 feed using maven configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You may try using an extension like [Build Chain](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=megoels.buildchain) or [Queue New Build](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=delegen.DelegenQueueNewBuild) or [Parallel Builds](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kneradovsky.viko-build-tasks). These extensions allows you to launch and wait for other builds in a Gated-checking Definition for test1 and test2 projects.